# jssor nested slider loop through problems with single picture in nested slide

Tags: nested, jssor

http://www.jssor.com/testcase/nested-slider-loop-through.source.html

^^^ With this example I have a Problem - if in the last nestedslider is only one Slide it switches nearly without break to the first nestedslide.

Comment: for me the link still works ... is a Autoplay example for the nested sliders.
In this example all works fine, but if I but under the slider "photography" only one picture - he Switch to the next - the first slider way to fast.

Comment: I see, if there is only one image in the child slider, it won't play automatically. So, you'd write custom code to control it.